# Add Draggable Imageview to relative layout from custom class android

Tags: android, android-layout, drag-and-drop, draggable, android-custom-view

How can i Add Image View to my relative layout at particular postion from my custom class that extends relative layout and make that imageview draggable to particular portion of layout ?
below is my custom class in which i want to add image.
so, should i add image on canvas view or simply on relative layout ? 
please give me an appropriate solution.

```
public class CustomCompassView extends RelativeLayout {

int width;
int height;
int saparationRatio;

int captureRange;

private ImageView mImage;

public CustomCompassView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomCompassView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public CustomCompassView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    mImage = (ImageView) getChildAt(2);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    super.onDraw(canvas);

    width = this.getWidth();
    height = this.getHeight();
    saparationRatio = (width / 2) / 5;

    Log.e(AppConstant.LOG_TAG, "height: " + height + " & width: " + width);

    drawCircleAbove125(canvas);

}

protected void drawCircleAbove125(Canvas canvas) {

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(0.0f);
    canvas.drawCircle(width / 2, height / 2, width / 2, paint);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inflate a layout in your relative layout class

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from (context);
View v = inflater.inflate (R.layout.some_file, null, true);

this.addView (v);
```

You can add whatever you like in inflated layout.

Comment: yes, but i want to add imageview on particular (x,y) postion and want to make it draggable also.how can i achieve this ?

Comment: you need to use bounds calculation to do that. You can read more about drag and drop here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html